# Set Future Limit to date picker

Tags: android, android-activity, datepicker

I don't want to show the future dates. I found many similar ans but i am using on few lines of code.

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            updateLabel();
        }
    };
    currentDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(ExerciseCDiaryActivity.this, date, c
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set DatePicker dialogue to current date and you will be fine like this

```
date.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: it says getDatePicker is undefined for type DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener

Comment: @pratz9999 I forgot to mention that it requires min API level 11 and if you are targeting below that then you have to make custom datepicker for that ...

Comment: @Darkie- I did something else now,  I am now comparing two dates, i.e today's date with selected date and then i am running toast that you cannot add future entries and redirecting user to same page with today's date.

Comment: @pratz9999 did you able to set the max date to current date ?

Comment: @pratz9999 yes you can do it just compare the dates and then through intent get the user to the activity you want to take it.

Comment: @pratz9999 what else now ?
and if the answer is right then mark it as an answer and upvote it ... :-)